# How to add views to the Browsable API Root?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When working with the [Browsable API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) in Django Rest Framework the API root only appears to list responses for `ViewSets` registered via a `router`.

For example, in the code below `users` and `accounts` would show, but not `forgot-password`:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^forgot-password/$', ForgotPasswordFormView.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

How can I add a hyperlink for `forgot-password` to the base API root?

Comment: The browsable API mostly work with Viewset, because the structure of viewset is already defined. Other than that you can see some screen in API url, but field list won't come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add below settings for `django-rest-framework`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ]
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me.